# Test observable evaluated only once

Tags: java, unit-testing, rx-java

We are using rx-java, but we have a problem to test if an Observable is evaluated only once.

We have the following signature of services:

```
class A {
  Observable<String> computeA();
}

class B {
  Observable<Void> computeB(String inputA)
}

class C {
  Observable<Void> computeC(String inputA)
}
```

In our case we have a service that invokes a service A, and we use the result of this service as input to another two service B and C. We want to check that the service A in only invoked once.

We tried to do it using AtomicInteger as a counter mocking the Observable of service A or just mocking Observable.OnSubscribe checking the times call is invoked, but the test turns very difficult to read.

The question is: Is there any cleaner way to do this kind of test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually do this by adding an

```
source
.doOnSubscribe(() -> counter.getAndIncrement())
.op()
.op()
...
```

at the required place and check the counter value after things quiet down.

Note that we have an operator called `publish()` that makes sure a source is subscribed to once and all side-effects of it happen only once (as long as connect() is called once).

Comment: This solution checks the number of subscribers, not the number of evaluating of the OnSubscribe events, if using `cache()` it will not work properly.

Comment: What do you mean by evaluating OnSubscribe events? Is it how many onNext events are fired?

Comment: every time someone subscribe to an observable it will evaluate the onsubscribe and the lambda. This can be cached using `cache()`, but we want to check that this evaluation is only invoked once

Comment: This still sounds like the number of subscribers because OnSubscribe gets evaluated for each Subscriber with cold Observables. What does your source look like and how would it be evaluated multiple times?

Comment: I was absolutely wrong.. If you do `myObservable.doOnSubscribe(count::incrementAndGet).cache()`.  the count will at most one, because if there is a second subscriber, it will return the values cached, so It will be perfect for my tests. But if done in the wrong way (which is what I understood) `myObservable.cache().doOnSubscribe(count::incrementAndGet)`, then you will get the number of subscribers to the cache, which is what I don't want. So, sorry and thank you ;)